# Проблема с добавлением данных в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Есть 2 модели, связанные связью многие-ко-многим. Мой вопрос: как можно реализовать добавление? какой код нужно написать для контроллера и для view?
Я хочу, чтобы пользователь мог сам вводить данные как о себе, так и о машине. 
Что мне нужно дописать, чтобы можно было добавить информацию о машине? Вот мой код:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int OwnerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Mark { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string YearofRelease { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
// GET: Owners/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "OwnerID,Name,Surname,Birthday,Experience")] Owner owner, [Bind(Include = "CarID,Model,Mark,Type,Price,YearOfRelease")] Car car )
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        owner.Cars.Add(car);
        db.Owners.Add(owner);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(owner);
}
```

Отображение

```
@model Site.Models.Owner

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

 <h2>Create</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     <div class="form-horizontal">
     <h4>Owner</h4>
     <hr />
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
         <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
         <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Experience, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Experience, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Experience, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Моделью Вашего представления является:

```
@model Site.Models.Owner
```

Если Вам необходимо обработать сразу и **Owner** и  **Car**, Вам необходимо передавать на форму необходимые данные. К примеру можно сделать промежуточную модель, в которой будет и **Owner** и  **Car**:

```
public class SpecialModel
{
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

и передавать эту модель в представление из контроллера. Соответсвенно Вам необходимо изменить методы под новый код. Вот пример того, что похоже на Вашу проблему:
[pass two models to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030399/pass-two-models-to-view)